How to solve a system of linear equations in Python with an iterative method?
I have a system of linear equations represented as strings in Python, and I need to find integer values (positive or negative) for each of the variables that satisfy all equations simultaneously without contradictions. The number of variables and equations can vary, so the solution should adapt accordingly.
Here's an example of such a system of equations:
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
import re

system_equations = [
'5 = X0 + Y0', 
'6 = X0 + Y1', 
'5 = X0 + Y3', 
'5 = X0 + Y4', 
'3 = X1 + Y2', 
'0 = X2 + Y2', 
'1 = X2 + Y4'
]


# Extract all variable names from the system of equations
variable_names = list(set(re.findall(r'[XY]\d+', ' '.join(system_equations))))

# Create symbols for the variables
variables = symbols(' '.join(variable_names))

It is important to keep in mind that the program must adapt to the number of variables (Xi and Yj) or/and equations that there are, this is just an example, where we have 8 unknowns and 7 linear equations.
For this example, one of the possible solutions where there are integer values that satisfy all the equations simultaneously (without contradictions), could be:
# a (posible) correct output
values_of_int_decomposition_variables = [['X0', 2], ['X1', 1], ['X2', -2], ['Y0', 3], ['Y1', 4], ['Y2', 2], ['Y3', 3], ['Y4', 3]]

Note that if they manage to satisfy all the equations:
ij_number_to_decompose = Xi + Yj

5 = 2 + 3
6 = 2 + 4
5 = 2 + 3
5 = 2 + 3
3 = 1 + 2
0 = 2 + (-2)
1 = -2 + 3

In the case of equations with the value of 0 it must necessarily be decomposed into 2 values equal in magnitude but of opposite sign (X2 and Y2 should have opposite values)

Does this answer your question? Is there a python module to solve linear equations?

@AbdulAzizBarkat It is similar although it has differences, since here it could not be known from the beginning how many variables there will be, that is why I am using regex. Furthermore, the format in which the output must be expressed is different (here I need a solution of exclusively integer numerical values associated with each variable). In the question, I have indicated the conditions under which the program should work and the output format

You can use PuLP or SciPY libraries for solving Linear Equations.
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
import re
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpVariable, value

system_equations = [
    '5 = X0 + Y0',
    '6 = X0 + Y1',
    '5 = X0 + Y3',
    '5 = X0 + Y4',
    '3 = X1 + Y2',
    '0 = X2 + Y2',
    '1 = X2 + Y4'
]

variable_names = list(set(re.findall(r'[XY]\d+', ' '.join(system_equations))))

variables = {var: LpVariable(var, lowBound=None, cat='Integer') for var in variable_names}

prob = LpProblem("IntegerLinearProgramming", LpMaximize)
print(variables)
for equation in system_equations:
    lhs, rhs = equation.split('=')
    lhs = lhs.strip()
    rhs = rhs.strip()
    print(rhs)
    terms = re.findall(r'([+-]?\s*\d*\s*\*?\s*[XY]\d+)', rhs)
    constraint = sum(eval(term, {}, variables) for term in terms) == int(lhs)
    prob += constraint

prob.solve()

values_of_int_decomposition_variables = [[var, int(value(variables[var]))] for var in variable_names]

print(values_of_int_decomposition_variables)


Thank you very much for the help, I hope it doesn't bother you but I could ask you if it is possible to make that code not allow the values that the variables take to be 0? That is, they can be positive (>0) or negative (<0) but not exactly zero.

Can you kindly explain the expectation once more

Dont worry, I think I fix thqat with this code line variables = {var: LpVariable(var, lowBound=-1, upBound=1, cat='Integer') for var in variable_names}

If you use SymPy you can let it tell you what variables are used. lpmax can be used, too, or you can solve in terms of a single variable (in this case):
>>> from sympy import *
# your definitions
>>> eqs = Tuple(*[Eq(*[S(i) for i in i.split('=')]) for i in system_equations]) 
>>> syms = var(str(eqs.free_symbols)) # local variables of symbols used in equation
>>> sol = solve(eqs,exclude=[X0]); sol
{Y0: 5 - X0, Y1: 6 - X0, Y3: 5 - X0, X1: X0 - 1, X2: X0 - 4, Y2: 4 - X0, Y4: 5 - X0}
>>> solve([sol[i]!=0 for i in sol])
[]

It looks like there is no way (for this system) to get all values to be non-zero. You can confirm by seeing that neither positive nor negative solutions in terms of x0 can be found:
>>> solve([sol[i]>0 for i in sol])
False
>>> solve([sol[i]<0 for i in sol])
False

